# Android Instrumentation to start Home Screen Activity

Tags: android, android-testing, instrumentation, homescreen

I'm looking for some help as to how to bring up the home screen during an Android test. Essentially I want to be able to send the application under test to the background and bring it back up later.

I tried using this code within my Instrumentation:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

And received this error:

> Intent in process com.norm.talk resolved to different process com.android.launcher

I have a loose understanding of why this is happening, something to do with the Instrumentation class only having access to the package associated with the Application under test. So obviously we'll have to try something different, anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Do you need to test the home button in the application? (Home button in the application not the device home button)

Answer (score 0):

It's look like that testing frameworks runs all your app in a one single process, and don't let you to move to other process